# Extending spanning sets on contractions of matroids

Tags: co.combinatorics, matroid-theory

Suppose you have a matroid, and $T$ is a subset of a spanning set $S$.

Now consider the contraction of the matroid to the set $T$ and suppose $X$ is a spanning subset of $T$ with respect to that matroid structure.

Is $(S\setminus T)\cup X$ a spanning set of the original matroid?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. If the complement $\bar{S}$ of $S$ is also spanning, then the contraction to $T$ is trivial and $X=\emptyset$ is spanning. But $S\setminus T$ is not necessarily spanning (it may be even empty: take $T=S$).

Comment: Thank you for the answer!